# What is the type keyword when used where you would normally put var?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

```
type StoreCreator = (reducer: Reducer, preloadedState: ?State) => Store
```

I've never come across this. What type?

As a unrelated follow up, what is `?State` ?

Comment: Some more context would be useful. Where did you come across this syntax?

Comment: I suspect that isn't actually JavaScript but is [a different programming language](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Comment: Sorry about that. It is from here:https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md

Comment: I assumed it was javascript, but since redux is agnostic, it is most likely another language now that you mention it.

Answer (score 3):

`type` is used for type aliases in typescript. For example:

```
type StringOrNumber = string | number;
```

> A type alias serves as an alias for the type specified in the type
>   alias declaration. Unlike an interface declaration, which always
>   introduces a named object type, a type alias declaration can introduce
>   a name for any kind of type, including primitive, union, and
>   intersection types.

Here you can find the docs: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.10